# Creating a Quad face with 3 vertices already created?

Tags: vertices

How do I proceed to make a quad (not necessarily same shape) at an 3 vertice edge? Extrude doesn't do the trick with the vertices selected and fill just creates a triangle~

[image: How to make this Quad]

Comment: Did you try to extrude only one vertex? This should provide the fourth vertex you need, which you can then use to build the extra edge/face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an add on included, called F2, go to Edit > Preferences > Addons and type F2 to search.

[image]

Then, select the corner vertex (in my case in the middle) and press <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you~

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any automatic way, but you can enable the *Snap to Vertex* mode, extrude, snap to the vertex (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if you haven't activated the *Snap* option itself), then fill:

[image]

Or keep the *Snap to Vertex* mode activated, also activate the *Auto Merge* option and duplicate snap one of your existing face:

[image]

Comment: So many useful methods! I finally know how to use the snapping correctly ~D

Comment: Yes, I didn't know Emir's method  ;)