# How can i fill this hole?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
Grid fill doesnt seem to work even if I set 7x7.

Comment: Hello, could you please share this part of your file so that we can try? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You could use this included add on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268098/creating-a-quad-face-with-3-vertices-already-created/268100#268100

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the best way is to do it manually by selecting loop pairs and bridging with the appropriate number of cuts to match the adjacent vertices. Then merging those vertices by distance.  You might be able to get close by running grid fill and then smoothing the vertices several times.