What does "F" do inside Edit Mode?
I've come to realize that when I press F in Edit Mode, it immediately closes my blender. Clearly, whatever the operation is, it is too much for my pc to handle in the current project.
My goal is to turn off the related keymap. I just can't find the specific keymap inside preferences. Can't seem to search it with F in the search bar.
Also don't see Edit Mode inside of keymap preferences.
Does anyone know what it is?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268098/creating-a-quad-face-with-3-vertices-already-created/268100#268100

F is Fill in Edit Mode... for example, if you select some vertices or edges it creates a face from them. Never heard it crashing Blender. And why do you press it when you don't know what it's for?

Ahh Thank you! I have now turned it off and my problem no longer exists. The reason that I kept pressing it is because of this: If you look at you're keyboard, "F" actually happens to be next to "G"! I happen use to the grab tool often, and therefore end up pressing "F" by mistake while in edit mode.

@Scrappy_Bogart Ah okay... yeah F is next to G but although I'm sometimes hitting wrong keys when typing, it never occurred to me to accidentally press F when wanting to move. Still, weird that hitting F immediately closes Blender, sounds like a bug. But since bugs are out of the scope of this site we cannot do much. By the way finding it in the keymap: search "f" in Key-Binding and when you scroll down under Mesh there the first entry (with F2 addon enabled) is "Make Edge/Face" from the addon. There is no Edit Mode category in the keymap, only Mesh or Curve (and Curves).

@GordonBrinkmann Blender often crashes when you try to connect too many vertices in an already connected mesh, so it may crash if you have a complex/subdivided object and accidentally fill everything.

@KISKAart Hm okay... most of the time my Blender becomes unresponsive if I do something very resource-intense like that, sometimes coming back, sometimes when I'm not patient enough or think it won't come back I kill the task... but immediately closing I usually only experience with bugs. But anyway, as I said it would be off-topic here if it were a bug.

Ok, voting to close. @Scrappy_Bogart try doing this with simple objects and loading factory settings.

Hey KiskAart, you are right, this blender crashing problem will not happen with simple object. My current project is a sculpt with over 10 million faces. I am working on the retopology today. I will reload factory settings or simply put F back into my shortcuts when I am done with retopo. Now, you said you were voting to close? Is that an action that I need to take on this forum to 'close out' the question? I am new here.

The question can be closed by community votes.  It's not a mark against your account and not necessary for you to do anything.  Thanks for following up.
